# How can I redirect to a "url" instead of "state" SAML-sso after login

Tags: angularjs, redirect, single-sign-on, router, passport-saml

Currently I am using SSO to login to my application.

I store cuurrent state of the page in variable RelayState and passes this to the Login url like this;

**/login?RelayState=/home**

After login, this redirect the URL to

**https://my_host/#/home**

But Now I want to change the URL instead of state, I am trying to redirect to the URL **https://my_host/new_home** after login.

But not sure how I can achive this. Is there any other query parameter similar to RelayState that I can pass? 
I am completely new to this SSO thing.
Can any one please help or let me know if the question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try to store full url: `?RelayState=https://my_host/new_home` or try to use [$window](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window) and [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) services.

```
var protocol = $location.protocol();
var host = $location.host();
var newHomeUrl = protocol + '://' + host + '/new_home';

$window.open(newHomeUrl,'_self');
```

// Probably You'll have to use encoded URL `?RelayState=https%3A%2F%2Fmy_host%2Fnew_home`